# echo does not display proper output

Tags: unix, ksh

Following code read the test.txt contents and based on first field it redirect third field to result.txt

```
src_fld=s1
type=11

Logic_File=`cat /home/script/test.txt`

printf '%s\n' "$Logic_File" |
{
while IFS=',' read -r line
do
fld1=`echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 1`
if [[ $type -eq $fld1 ]];then
   query=`echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 3-`
   echo $query >> /home/stg/result.txt
fi
done
}
```

Following is the contents of test.txt:

```
6,STRING TO DECIMAL WITHOUT DEFAULT,cast($src_fld as DECIMAL(15,2) $tgt_fld 
7,STRING TO INTERGER WITHOUT DEFAULT,cast($src_fld as integer) $tgt_fld                
11,DEFAULT NO RULE,$src_fld
```

everything works fine except output in result.txt is $src_fld instead of s1. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the below line

```
   echo $query >> /home/stg/result.txt
```

with this one

```
   eval "echo $query" >> /home/stg/result.txt
```

Comment: @user1768029 if that answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking the check mark next to it.  You will both get reputation for it and others will know it has an accepted answer